# Use JavaScript to change image when hovering over text, and change text when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, css

I have this JavaScript code that changes the opacity of an image when you hover over a related anchor tag. I was wondering how to get it to also work in reverse? Change the anchor tag when hovering over the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/7EzuS/8/

JavaScript

```
$('.link a').hover(
function () {
    $('img.'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('hovered');
    },
function () { 
    $('img.'+$(this).attr('class')).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#" class="link_a">Link A</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#" class="link_b">Link B</a></div></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img class="link_a" src="http://somthing.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img class="link_b" src="http://somthing.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.hovered     {opacity: 1.0;}
img          {opacity: 0.5;}
img:hover    {opacity: 1.0;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in this anchor tag?

Comment: @KeluThatsall I'll change the colour of the anchor tag text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deal with ids rather than classes in this case in order to have a generic solution, Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7EzuS/13/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#" id="link_a" class="hoverLink">Link A</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#" id="link_b" class="hoverLink">Link B</a></div></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="link_a_img" class="hoverImg" src="http://images.apple.com/support/ipod/images/do_not_disconnect_icon.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="link_b_img" class="hoverImg" src="http://atlanta.braves.mlb.com/images/global/alert_icon.gif" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.link a').hover(
function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_img').addClass('hovered');
},
function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_img').removeClass('hovered');
});
$('img.hoverImg').hover(
function () {
    var idParts = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var id = idParts[0] + "_" + idParts[1];
    $('#' + id).addClass('hovered');
},
function () {
    var idParts = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var id = idParts[0] + "_" + idParts[1];
    $('#' + id).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hovered     {opacity: 1.0; font-weight:bold;}
img          {opacity: 0.5;}
img:hover    {opacity: 1.0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/7EzuS/12/)** and let me know if you have any questions.

```
$('.link a').hover(
        function () {
            $('img.'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('hovered');
            },
        function () { 
            $('img.'+$(this).attr('class')).removeClass('hovered');
        });

$('img.link_a').hover(
        function () {
            $('a.link_a').addClass('hovered');
            },
        function () { 
            $('a.link_a').removeClass('hovered');
        });

$('img.link_b').hover(
        function () {
            $('a.link_b').addClass('hovered');
            },
        function () { 
            $('a.link_b').removeClass('hovered');
        });
```